# php module/library in c9

Tags: php, cloud9-ide

Anyone here uses c9 (https://c9.io/)? How can I install the `php` module/library in c9? Is there a relation between the module/library and this `$ch = curl_init();` for having an error of **Call to undefined curl_init()** Because, I just copy-paste a code that was given to me, and I have an error like that. I seriously don't know anything about this, I've googled it but nothing seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a relation between the call and the library, or in this case the absence of the CURL library. PHP supports many built-in functions, but for using third party libraries often a module needs be installed/included. To make curl functions work in Cloud9, execute following  (without the quotes) from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

That should make the PHP code work.